# Monitoring a Custom Service

Tags: vb.net

I've created a service for one of my apps.  How do i create a system tray component in VB.net that can be used to monitor the progress of the service?  Is there a way to have this installed via tcpip on multiple client machines such as those that are for our employees?

Answer (score 1):

We do exactly that here, with the server running a really basic HTTP server on a configurable port on a separate thread that returns status in an XML format (nothing else, just that) -- the client just uses a web request to get the XML, before parsing it and displaying it appropriately.

This approach also allows for future extensibility (detailed status, sending service control commands, adding an association to an XSLT file elsewhere for use with a normal web browser, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use WCF for this.  Using WCF your service would open up an EndPoint which would expose status information to callers.  You could then build a tray icon application that can be deployed to the employees workstations.  The tray icon application could periodically poll the WCF service the your Windows Service is hosting and get status information.  I know @Johan mentioned Remoting already and this is a similar approach.  I'd recommend WCF though as the programming API is more simple, IMHO, and WCF will give you more flexibility with regards to network transports, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is not about how to actually do the "traybar"-thing, but how to communicate with the service to get the information you want to show in the monitor/traybar-program?

It can be done in many ways, API is one way, use sendmessage/postmessage/getmessage is one way to make 2 running programs communicate with each other without having to store anything in files or databases first.

DDE is another way. If it needs to do the stuff via net then there is something called NetDDE, but I havent done anything with NetDDE I cant help anything there.

But about the API and DDE, feel free to ask more questions if you want some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take the second question: Is there a way to remotely install software on client machines?

Yes.  However it is very dependent on your environment.  For example, if you have an Active Directory domain, you can use group policy to force installation of software on the client boxes.

If you don't like that or if you aren't on active directory, you can buy something like Altiris to push installs down.

Another option would be to use login scripts which would run a custom program to detect if your program is installed and take appropriate action.  But then you are probably better off buying Altiris.

Answer (score 0):

For the comunication part, i have used remoting before, and this works very well. With a little bit of configuration, you can even get it working to another machine.